# Who wins the pot?

Tags: texas-hold-em

In a four handed game the board shows flush with A,K,J,T, 2 clubs; all players remain in through the river.  No player had the Q, UTG - had 3 clubs; MP - had 5 clubs; remaining players don't have a club.  Is this a split pot four ways?

Comment: Please look at the aforementioned post to understand the rules of split pots, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Best 5 cards every time

5 is greater than 2
5 is greater than 3

A,K,J,T,5 clubs wins